# How to migrate svn to another repository without svndump

Tags: svn, svnadmin

I need to migrate from one SVN server to different SVN server.

Problem in my case is I do not have shell access to the current server.

I do not have svnadmin user either.

I have some web based panel where I can make repo's and users.

I can not just do "svnadmin dump ".

I see there is svnrdump command but for some reason it is not present on my server.

I found this http://rsvndump.sourceforge.net/, but not sure if it is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

svnrdump is part of Subversion 1.7.x.

However it is not requires the server to be 1.7.x, and works fine against 1.6